# Xcode swift : connection from buttons to Text Fields

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, textfield

I am new to swift programming and Xcode

However I am creating a dart counter app but having trouble connecting the buttons to Text fields

I have buttons numbered 0-20 on the main story board and three text fields (one for each dart) how do I connect the buttons to the UITextFields - I can’t figure this out

Thanks

[image]

Comment: "how do I connect the buttons to the UITextFields"  Explain what you mean by connecting buttons to the text fields.

Comment: So the three text fields (DartOne, DartTwo...)i want them to be filled when the user hits the number (button) and hits enter then move onto the next untill all three are filled and added to the label

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your issue, you actually need to connect the buttons to the text field in code. There is not going to be a simple way to do this in the interface builder. What you are looking for is to have some action happen when the user presses a number, and this may be added to the current value in the text field.

1. Create a function that handles any number button being pressed.

   ```
   @IBAction func buttonPress(sender: UIButton) {
       print(sender.tag)
       //TODO: process the button based on its tag
   }
   ```
2. Update all of the buttons in interface builder to have a tag value according to their number. This will let you handle them all in the same function (above) and differentiate between them.
3. Update the TODO block to handle the action appropriately. I would start by adding a variable to keep track of which dart number you are on, and using a switch statement to handle putting the value in the appropriate dart text box.

Answer (score 0):

So there is always a current text field. Maintain an instance property that points to it. When the user taps a number, use that instance property to enter that value in that text field. When the user taps Enter, change the instance property to point to the next text field.